# How do I read from one worksheet and write into another sheet in same excelsheet

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am getting below error in my code -
java.lang.NullPointerException at CopyOfPMCTest.main(CopyOfPMCTest.java:91)

Code on Line 91 is sheet1.getRow(rowNo).createCell(0).setCellValue(vNo);

I debug the code and the sheet1 object is null which is causing the error.

```
// Reading of Excel sheet
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Jayesh\\PMC\\PMCAutomation\\PMCDemo\\TestData\\TestSheet.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);// This is for reading V numbers in excelsheet -Sheet1
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheetAt(1);// This is for writing the result in same excelsheet - Sheet2
    XSSFRow row;
    int initialRow=0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(i);
        int vNo = (int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
        // Owner Details
        String ownerName = "Jayesh B";
        String ownerAddress = "Add1, Add2, India";

        List<Object> Measurement = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");
        Measurement.add(1);
        Measurement.add("Test");

        // Below code is to write the VNo, Owner Name, OwnerAddress, and Measurement details
        int iterator = 0;
        int totalRows = 2;
        System.out.println("Total Rows: "+totalRows);
        int totalCols = 12;
        System.out.println("Total Cols: "+totalCols);
        int colNo;
        for (int rowNo = initialRow+1; rowNo <= initialRow+totalRows; rowNo++) {
            sheet1.getRow(rowNo).createCell(0).setCellValue(vNo);
            sheet1.getRow(rowNo).createCell(1).setCellValue(ownerName);
            sheet1.getRow(rowNo).createCell(2).setCellValue(ownerAddress);
                for (colNo = 3; colNo <= totalCols + 1; colNo++) {
                sheet1.getRow(rowNo).createCell(colNo)
                        .setCellValue(Measurement.get(iterator).toString());
                iterator = iterator + 1;
    }
            iterator = iterator + 1;

    }
        initialRow=initialRow+totalRows;
    }

    fis.close();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Jayesh\\PMC\\PMCAutomation\\PMCDemo\\TestData\\TestSheet.xlsx");
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();

}
```

I expect the code to read vNo from first sheet and then write it along with ownerName, address and Measurement details on second sheet of same excelsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception error fixed after making below change in Line 91 - 
sheet1.**createRow**(rowNo).createCell(0).setCellValue(vNo);

After debugging the code, I found that the object was not null, so the issue was with the methods I called using the object. With getRow() method it was unable to find out the row, so I added createRow() method to create row and then set the value at a particular cell location. And this change worked for me. I run the code for multiple times and there are no further issues observed.